# Magneto 2 : How to Integrate my Magento store into Jet Marketplace?

Tags: integration

I have **Magento Store** and looking for integration of **jet.com** for my product listing page. Is this possible way to do this?  Please suggest me. Other things I have India based website.

I hope that anyone have this solution .

Thank you.

Comment: Please, provide us more information on your question: What Magento version you are using? What you already tried to make for achievement of your purpose and what problems have faced?

Comment: You can't Sell on Jet.com  as it is completely for USA based retailers and online store owners. It allows them to integrate their e-commerce store with their marketplace through a 3rd Party API. You can read more about this over here - https://www.quora.com/How-can-a-retailer-get-their-products-sold-on-Jet

Comment: As Jet marketplace is totally for US merchants. Although if you have seller account then you can integrate module as follows: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mkmage-jet-integrate.html